# Высчитать возраста пользователя в днях java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Задача: Надо рассчитать возраст пользователя, в днях, часах, минутах. Вводится дата рождения и сегодняшняя дата.

Вроде как, возраст рассчитывает правильно, но в днях получается не правильная цифра. Как рассчитать разницу между  датами в днях?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int day;
        int year;
        int month;
        int day2; //сегодняшний день
        int year2; //сегодняшний год
        int month2; //сегодняшний месяц
        do {
            System.out.print("Введите год рождения: ");
            year = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (year < 1000 || year > 2019);

        do {
            System.out.print("Введите месяц рождения: ");
            month = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (month < 1 || month > 12);

        do {
            System.out.print("Введите день рождения: ");
            day = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (day < 1 || day > 31);


        do {
            System.out.print("Введите сегодняшний год: ");
            year2 = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (year2 < 1000 || year2 > 2019);

        do {
            System.out.print("Введите сегодняшний месяц: ");
            month2 = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (month2 < 1 || month2 > 12);

        do {
            System.out.print("Введите сегодняшний день: ");
            day2 = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (day2 < 1 || day2 > 31);


        int year_leap;
        int[] month_day = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) {
            year_leap = 366;
            month_day[1] = 29;
        } else {
            month_day[1] = 28;
            year_leap = 365;
        }


        int userYear = 0;
        int userMonth;
        int userDay;

        if (year <= year2) {
            userYear = year2 - year;
        } else System.out.printf("Ошибка!!! %n");

        if (month > month2) {
            userYear--;
            userMonth = month2 + 12 - month;
        } else userMonth = month2 - month;

        if (day > day2) {
            userMonth--;
            userDay = day2 + month_day[userMonth] - day;
        } else userDay = day2 - day;


        int day_year = 0;
        int day_month = 0;
        int day_age = 0;


        while (year < year2 - 1) {

            if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) {
                year_leap = 366;
                month_day[1] = 29;
            } else {
                year_leap = 365;
                month_day[1] = 28;

            }
            year++;
            day_year = day_year + year_leap;
        }

        day_month = month_day[1] * userMonth + userDay;
        day_age = day_year + day_month;

        System.out.printf("------------------------------------ %n");
        System.out.println("Ваш возраст: " + userYear + "." + userMonth + "." + userDay);
        System.out.println("Ваш возраст в днях: " + day_age);

    }
}
```

Нашел нужный алгоритм на Python. Как его реализовать на Java?

```
def dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
return (year1, month1, day1) < (year2, month2, day2)



def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
assert not dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)
days = 0
while dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
days += 1
year1, month1, day1 = nextDay(year1, month1, day1)
return days
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0 - возраст в днях - разность двух юлианских дат...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(2010, 5, 17); //
    LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.of(2010, 7, 7); // 
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate);
    System.out.println("daysBetween "+daysBetween);//daysBetween 51
}

}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html